# Existence of a $C_c^{\infty}$ function $\Phi$ s.t. $\int \nabla \Phi \neq 0.$

Tags: lebesgue-measure, smooth-functions

> Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be open, bounded and connected set with $\mathcal{L^n}(\Omega)>0$. Let $\Omega=\Omega_1\cup\Omega_2$ where $\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2=\emptyset$ with $\mathcal{L^n}(\Omega_1)>0$ and $\mathcal{L^n}(\Omega_2)>0.$ Also $\Omega_1,$ $\Omega_2$ are $\mathcal L^n$-measurable sets.  Prove that  $\exists$ $\Phi\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ such that $\displaystyle \int_{\Omega_1}\nabla\Phi(x)dx\neq 0.$

Here $\Phi$ is real valued function and $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ consists of all $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ functions which have compact support in $\Omega.$

**I tried to show by contradiction and wished to have $\mathcal{L^n}(\Omega_1)=0 $ but couldn't be able to do that.**

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, let for all $\Phi\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega),$ $\int\limits_{\Omega_1}\nabla\Phi=0.$

Then 
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{\Omega_1}\nabla\Phi=0&\implies \int\limits_{\Omega_1}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_i}=0\ \ \ \ \ \  \forall\ \ 1\leq i\leq n\ \ \textrm{ and }\ \forall\  \Phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)\\
&\implies\int\limits_{\Omega}\chi_{\Omega_1} \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_i}=0 \ \ \ \ \ \  \forall\ \ 1\leq i\leq n\ \ \textrm{ and }\ \forall\  \Phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)\\
&\implies T_{\chi_{\Omega_1}}\left(\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_i}\right)=0\ \ \ \ \ \  \forall\ \ 1\leq i\leq n\ \ \textrm{ and }\ \forall\  \Phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega),
\end{align}
where $T_{\chi_{\Omega_1}}$ is a distribution on $\Omega$ defined by $T_{\chi_{\Omega_1}}(\Phi)=\int\limits_{\Omega}\chi_{\Omega_1}  \Phi \ \ \ \ \forall \ \ \Phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega),\ $ i.e.,  $T_{\chi_{\Omega_1}}: C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)\to \mathbb R.$

From the property of distribution<sup>*</sup>, $$T_{\chi_{\Omega_1}}\left(\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x_i}\right)=-\frac{\partial T_{\chi_{\Omega_1}}}{\partial x_i}(\Phi)$$

So $\frac{\partial T_{\chi_{\Omega_1}}}{\partial x_i}=0 \ \ \ \ \forall 1\leq i\leq n.$

$\implies T_{\chi_{\Omega_1}}=T_k=$ constantly distributed operator, where $k\in \mathbb R$.

$\implies \int\limits_{\Omega}\chi_{\Omega_1}\Phi=\int\limits_{\Omega} k\Phi \ \ \ \ \forall \ \Phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$

$\implies \int\limits_{\Omega}\left(\chi_{\Omega_1}-k\right)\Phi=0 \ \ \ \ \forall \ \Phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$

$\implies \chi_{\Omega_1}=k$ a.e. $\Omega$ $\ \ \ $[By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus of Variations]

$\implies \mathcal L^n(\Omega_2)=0,$ which is a contradiction.

Therefore, we can conclude that there exists a $C_c^{\infty}$ function $\Phi$ on $\Omega$ such that $\int\limits_{\Omega_1}\nabla \Phi\neq 0.$

**Note: Definition of distribution can be seen at the definition $1.2.2$ in the book 'Topics in Functional Analysis and Applications' by S. Kesavan.**

***Definition(distribution): A linear functional $T$ on $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is said to be distribution on $\Omega$ if whenever $\Phi_m\to 0$ in $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ we have $T(\Phi_m)\to 0.$***

<sup>*<sub>It's proved in the last part of the comment $3.$ Fundamental Solutions (Before the exercise section) in the first chapter 'Distribution' of the book 'Topics in Functional Analysis and Applications' by S. Kesavan. Also it's on the exercise $1.2$</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Assuming $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are measurable, then there exists compact set $F\subset \Omega_1$ such that $\mathcal{L}^n(F)+\varepsilon=\mathcal{L}^n(\Omega_1)$. Likewise, there exists open set $G\supset \Omega_1$ such that $\mathcal{L}^n(G)-\varepsilon=\mathcal{L}^n(\Omega_1)$. Hence $\mathcal{L}^n(G\cap\Omega_2)$ is small.

Then by smooth Urysohn's lemma there exists $\Phi$ smooth such that $\Phi \equiv 1$ on $F$ and $\Phi\equiv 0$ on $G^c$.

Comment: If we take $\Omega=(0,2)=(0,1]\cup(1,2)=\Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$ then $G^c$ will not contain $\Omega_2$

Comment: @nurunnesha Yes. I made the correction.

Comment: But we need $\int_{\Omega_1} \nabla \Phi \neq 0.$ So will we have to construct this $\Phi$ on $\Omega_1\setminus F$ in such a way that $\nabla \Phi$ does not vanish there?

Comment: @nurunnesha Well. $\Phi$ needs to transition from $1$ to $0$ so $\nabla\Phi$ will not be small. You could also make $F$ smaller.